# PHPUnit & Composer: [InvalidArgumentException] Command "path/to/test" is not defined

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I have a directory with PHPUnit tests.
Running

```
$ phpunit path/to/dir/*.php
```

Get an error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                            
Command "path/to/dir/test_name.php" is not defined.
```

Where *test_name* is the name of the first test in a directory.

I add Composer in the title, because if hide it in the test bootstrap, appear an error that missed *Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php*

What I have missed or what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the path, no filenames:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit path/to/dir
```

`phpunit` will automatically detect test files in that folder and it's subfolders. Note that I'm using the executable from `vendor/bin` because you said that you've installed using composer.

Comment: I remember this should work, but if I call $phpunit /path/to/dir I got next:

PHPUnit 4.0.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Time: 19 ms, Memory: 1.75Mb

No tests executed!

Comment: Then there are no *valid* tests in that folder

Comment: Put there a test from the manual (http://phpunit.de/getting-started.html), the same result

Comment: PHPUnit was installed via Composer (may be it can tips something).

Now:$ phpunit --bootstrap path/to/bootstrap path/to/dir
Result:
  #!/usr/bin/env php
                                                                   
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                       
  Command "path/to/bootstrap.php" is not defined.

Comment: When it was installed using composer I expect that you need to call `vendor/bin/phpunit path/to/dir`

Comment: $ vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap path/to/bootstrap.php path/to/dir
Result:
#!/usr/bin/env php
                                                                   
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                       
  Command "path/to/bootstrap.php" is not defined.

Comment: <?php
require_once '/usr/local/bin/composer';

set_include_path(...);

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
spl_autoload_register('Zend_Loader::loadClass');

Comment: Replace the first line by `require_once 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php'`